# Demeaning binary variable

Tags: regression, mean, fixed-effects-model

I was confused regarding fixed effects regression model. Suppose I have a panel dataset with data on firms across several years. Introducing firm fixed effects and estimating deviations from means (average of each firm across time period) is algebraically the same. But what if one of my predictors in a binary variable. In case I want to see this equivalence by running the regression in STATA, how do I demean the binary variable?

Comment: You can compute the mean of the binary variable and subtract it from the variable, just as you would with any other variable. What makes you think they need to be treated differently?

Comment: When I tried running the two regressions without the binary variable, I got the exact same coefficient value. But after adding demeaned binary variable and untransformed binary variable to the FE model, the coefficients of both binary and continuous variable are different. Why is that so?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and code to illustrate your point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some R code illustrating Noah's point that there is no real difference between either approach.

```
library(plm)

m = 20
n = 8

step = 5
alpha = runif(n,seq(0,step*n,by=step),seq(step,step*n+step,by=step))
beta1 = -2
beta2 = 3

y = X = D = matrix(NA,nrow=m,ncol=n)
for (i in 1:n) {
  X[,i] = runif(m,i,i+1)
  D[,i] = rbinom(m, size=1, prob = .5)
  y[,i] = alpha[i] + X[,i]*beta1 + D[,i]*beta2 + rnorm(m, sd=1.5)  
}
stackX = as.vector(X)
stackD = as.vector(D)
stackY = as.vector(y)

MX = as.vector(demean(X))
MD = as.vector(demean(D))
My = as.vector(demean(y))

paneldata = data.frame(rep(1:n,each=m), rep(1:m,n), stackY, stackX, stackD) # first two columns are for plm to understand the panel structure

> summary(plm(stackY~stackX+stackD, data = paneldata, model = "within"))
Oneway (individual) effect Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = stackY ~ stackX + stackD, data = paneldata, model = "within")

Balanced Panel: n = 8, T = 20, N = 160

Residuals:
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-4.06709 -0.86746 -0.06579  1.06084  3.63538 

Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
stackX -3.00068    0.45162 -6.6443 5.282e-10 ***
stackD  3.33357    0.25785 12.9285 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    891.69
Residual Sum of Squares: 377.73
R-Squared:      0.57639
Adj. R-Squared: 0.55097
F-statistic: 102.05 on 2 and 150 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16

> summary(lm(My~MX+MD-1))

Call:
lm(formula = My ~ MX + MD - 1)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.0671 -0.8675 -0.0658  1.0608  3.6354 

Coefficients:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
MX  -3.0007     0.4400  -6.819 1.84e-10 ***
MD   3.3336     0.2512  13.269  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.546 on 158 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5764,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5
```